# C# printing datagridview to pdf file with microsoft print to file programatically without typing filename

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, datagridview, bitmap

So I want to print my data grid view as a bitmap using the Microsoft print to file and automatically name the file and set directory. Printing my datagridview to a printer works. Whenever I try to print it to a file I just get a blank page. How can I get it to print to the file instead of the printer.

//generate a file name as the current date/time in unix timestamp format

```
                string file = (string)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 
                1))).TotalSeconds.ToString();

                // the directory to store the output.
                string directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

                // initialize PrintDocument object
                PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument()
                {

                    PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
                    {
                        // set the printer to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
                        PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",

                        // tell the object this document will print to file
                        PrintToFile = true,

                        // set the filename to whatever you like (full path)
                        PrintFileName = Path.Combine(directory, file + ".pdf"),
                    }
                };

                printDocument1.Print();



    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgse)
    {

        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height);
        dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.dataGridView1.Width, 
        this.dataGridView1.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
    }
```